# How to bind ValueChanged of DecimalUpDown Control on ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, mvvm

```xaml
<xctk:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding TotalAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                  Width="120" Height="21" Margin="5 0 0 0" />
```

Comment: you cannot bind "ValueChanged" it's an event. please clarify the problem and show us what have you tried and which part didn't work.

Comment: There are 3 DecimalUpDown 2 of them when ValueChanged will get the the sum to the other DecimalUpDown. Its like DecimalUpDown3 = DecimalUpDown1 + DecimalUpDown2 everytime DecimalUpDown1 or DecimalUpDown2 value changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVVM, you would put the `ValueChanged` logic in the setter of the `TotalAmount` source property as this property gets set then when value is changed, e.g.:

```
public decimal TotalAmount
{
    get { return _totalAmout; }
    set { _totalAmount = value; PropertyBoundToDecimalUpDown3 = _totalAmount + _otherAmount; }
}
```

There is no reason to handle the event itself when you bind to a source property.

Answer (score 0):

You must write your logic inside the callback of each property. The `ValueChanged` event handler approach requires tightly coupled code behind and it will break the MVVM pattern.

If you prefer the DP way:

```
    public decimal Value1
    {
        get { return (decimal)GetValue(Value1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Value1Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Value1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value1", typeof(decimal), typeof(MyVM), 
            new PropertyMetadata(0m, (d, e) =>
            {
                var vm = d as MyVM;
                vm.TotalValue = e.NewValue + vm.Value2;
            }));

    public decimal Value2
    {
        get { return (decimal)GetValue(Value2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Value2Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Value2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value2", typeof(decimal), typeof(MyVM), 
            new PropertyMetadata(0m, (d, e) =>
            {
                var vm = d as MyVM;
                vm.TotalValue = e.NewValue + vm.Value1;
            }));
```

Or if you prefer the `INotifyPropertyChanged` way:

```
    public decimal Value1
    {
        get => _value1;
        set { 
            _value1 = value; 
            TotalValue = value + Value2;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public decimal Value2
    {
        get => _value2;
        set
        {
            _value2 = value;
            TotalValue = value + Value1;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Note that writing `TotalValue = ...` will handle its own NotifyPropertyChanged. However writing `_totalValue = ...` does not.